# Translation not working with <depends /> node

Tags: magento-enterprise, onepage-checkout, onestepcheckout

What I am doing is nothing but just injecting some custom code/script via reference `before_body_end` of layout handle `onestepcheckout_index_index` (some third party module for one step checkout).

I have a custom module for doing this which looks like this:

**Module**: app/etc/modules/MagePsycho_Autofill.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <MagePsycho_Autofill>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Idev_OneStepCheckout />
            </depends>
        </MagePsycho_Autofill>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**Layout**: app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/layout/magepsycho_autofill.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <onestepcheckout_index_index>
        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="magepsycho_autofill/autofill" template="magepsycho_autofill/autofill/checkout_scripts.phtml" name="magepsycho_autofill.checkout_scripts" as="autofill_checkout_scripts" />
        </reference>
    </onestepcheckout_index_index>
</layout>
```

And the custom module is working fine i.e. injects the checkout_scripts.phtml to a third party page.

**BUT** the problem is, all the translation of third-party modules is gone.

And if you remove the `<depends />` node, the translation of labels works fine but the custom module file is not injecting into the third party page. That's the reason I used `<depends />` node.

I tried to x-debug the translation, in both cases (with and without `<depends />` node) values for `$code` `$text` were the same and that was related to the third party itself. Even I tried to set the setModuleName() to a third party name in my block class but nothing is changing.

Can anyone tell me why and how to fix this weird behavior of translation?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have developer mode on?

Comment: Yes it's in developer mode.

Comment: If you deactivate developer mode it should work. If you want to know more about it, check this method in Magento Core https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.9.0.0/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php#L249

Comment: If you confirm that it's working without dev mode I can give you a bit more insight if you like in a proper answer

Comment: Nope it's not working even in production mode.